# How to handle errors: Pyntc ssh to network device

Tags: python, python-3.x, netmiko

I am new to network automation, and trying to use pyntc to ssh to the device. I am not sure how to write the code correctly to handle the ssh timeout or authentication error, etc.

**My code is as below:**

```
from pyntc import ntc_device as NTC
from pyntc_devices_list import Get_Devices_List

all_devices = Get_Devices_List()

for device in all_devices:
        print('Backing up ' + device['name'])
        DEVICE = NTC(host=device['ip'], username=device['username'], password=device['password'], device_type='cisco_ios$
    try:
            DEVICE.open()
    except Exception:
            print('Error')
            continue

    back_config = DEVICE.backup_running_config(device['name'] + '.cfg')
    DEVICE.close()
```

I manually turned off this device, and then I found python code was quit:

```
root@Network-Automation:~/Pyntc# python3 pyntc_error_handling.py
Backing up ESW1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 884, in establish_connection
    self.remote_conn_pre.connect(**ssh_connect_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 368, in connect
    raise NoValidConnectionsError(errors)
paramiko.ssh_exception.NoValidConnectionsError: [Errno None] Unable to connect to port 22 on 192.168.122.72

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyntc_error_handling.py", line 8, in <module>
    DEVICE = NTC(host=device['ip'], username=device['username'], password=device['password'], device_type='cisco_ios_ssh')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyntc/__init__.py", line 38, in ntc_device
    return device_class(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyntc/devices/ios_device.py", line 42, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyntc/devices/ios_device.py", line 300, in open
    verbose=False,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/netmiko/ssh_dispatcher.py", line 246, in ConnectHandler
    return ConnectionClass(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 317, in __init__
    self._open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 322, in _open
    self.establish_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 890, in establish_connection
    raise NetMikoTimeoutException(msg)
netmiko.ssh_exception.NetMikoTimeoutException: Connection to device timed-out: cisco_ios 192.168.122.72:22
```

Looks like there are more than 1 errors ...

Comment: first error can generate second error - so you may have only one real error.

Comment: Thanks furas, then how can I write the code to handle these errors ? Looks like the current "exception" does not work ...

Comment: is this all your code ? Error shows problem in `DEVICE = NTC(...)` which I don't see in your code. Maybe you should put all code in `try/except`, not only `DEVICE.open()`

Comment: Apologize ... Now I have put the whole code. I have 3 devices in the 'pyntc_devices_list', and use a "for" loop to backup the device config. I hope the try/exception can handle any error, so the code is able to continue to backup the next device, rather than quit the code.

Comment: your `try/except` catch error only for line `DEVICE.open()` but you get error in line `DEVICE = NTC(...)` which is not inside `try` so it could catch it. If you want to catch every error then you may have to put all code in `try`.

Comment: It works ... much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a minor mistake here, you are expecting an error than trying to same the output. In case of error, the script will through an error. Try it this way.

```
from pyntc import ntc_device as NTC
from pyntc_devices_list import Get_Devices_List

all_devices = Get_Devices_List()
try:
    for device in all_devices:
        print('Backing up ' + device['name'])
        DEVICE = NTC(host=device['ip'], username=device['username'], password=device['password'], device_type='cisco_ios')
        DEVICE.open()
        back_config = DEVICE.backup_running_config(device['name'] + '.cfg')
        DEVICE.close()
except Exception as Err:
    print(Err)
```